# HTML5 App Screen Sleep/Timeout on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, html

We're currently developing an HTML 5 app for the iPad and looking for a method to prevent the screen from going to standby/sleep. I understand this is possible with a native iOS app but what about an HTML5-based web application?

Thank you for any suggestions and answers.

Comment: I've posted some findings on one way to do this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709891/prevent-ios-mobile-safari-from-going-idle-auto-locking-sleeping

Comment: You can do this using an HTML5 audio element, in a playback loop: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15210029/1539698

Comment: I managed to prevent sleep in my Webapp: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17912979/784318

Comment: I am OK with my iPhone going to lockscreen but would like for the audio controls to continue working and for my HTML/JavaScript web app to continue feeding the audio player new tracks. This seems to have broken in iOS 8?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope, you can't do this with a plain website/web app.

One option could be to create a native app containing simply a UIWebView. The native app would contain code to load your web app into the webview and disable the idle timer. (It's the idle timer that puts the iPad to sleep.)

Comment: Seems like a logical workaround. Does the UIWebView use the same rendering engine as Safari and support the same HTML5 standards?

Comment: It supports the same HTML5 standards, but IIRC it uses a different rendering engine: Mobile Safari can render a webpage partially/incrementall, a UIWebView can't. This makes a UIWebView appear slower when loading a webpage.

Comment: I think this will require some testing but it's certainly an option. I'll accept the answer and post back any relevant findings. thanks!

Comment: And then you'll be at risk of not being accepted on the app store ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478848/does-apple-reject-mobile-web-shell-applications

Answer (score 2):

Adjusted settings to not let the iPad lock the screen. Fired up a page that uses websockets. In an simple interval I used the socket to send and recieve a message every 60s. Worked for a couple of hours, then I closed it.

I also tried to switch tabs. Worked.

Answer (score 0):

Standby/sleep modes are rooted to the OS, so it's pretty much impossible to achieve with HTML5.
Why would you do this anyway? Maybe you could think of a timeout function in case the device was in standby/sleep and came back. [This answer looks useful but I haven't yet test it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543325/what-happens-to-javascript-execution-settimeout-etc-when-iphone-android-goes)