# keep device from sleeping via website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering if it is possible to keep all devices (phones, tablets and computers) from shutting off the screen using a website.

I am building an order receiving system via a website, now I want the keep the screen from shutting off so that the costumer will not miss the orders and does not have to keep turning on the device. Is there a way to do this in a website?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905413/how-can-i-prevent-iphone-including-ios-7-from-going-to-sleep-in-html-or-js

Comment: That's not something that you should be thinking off. That's the user's decision.

Comment: I don't think people will be happy with that

Comment: It is for restaurants who'll receive orders and they need to accept/decline within 5 min. If the screen shuts off, it is a big chance they will miss it and it will get automaticly declined

Comment: @Pimmmo Then they need to configure their computer not to shut off. It's not up to a *website* to override their settings.

Comment: in the future:

https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5768542523752448