# How to prevent iPhone from going idle / sleep when running webapp started from home screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, web-applications, sleep, homescreen

I have written an HTML5 webapp and need to prevent an iPhone (iOS 7) from going idle while running it. I came across the [reload trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24351683/3790755) which works perfectly, but only when I open the app's URL in Safari. When I add the app to the homescreen so it is started in standalone mode (a.k.a. native mode, app mode, fullscreen mode, ...), the reload trick does not work anymore and the iPhone goes to sleep after the usual period of time. [Looping an audio file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15210029/3790755) only keeps the iPhone alive a bit longer than usual. Looping a video simply starts the iPhone's video player, which does not help either. I use the `apple-mobile-web-app-capable`-meta tag in my webapp.

So does anyone know how I can solve this problem? Maybe there is a modification to the reload trick so it works again in standalone mode?

Thanks in advance!