# Avoid screen locking on mobile website

Tags: javascript, mobile, youtube, web, lockscreen

Is there any way of preventing a device to "sleep" when on the website?

(Desirable because of playing YouTube videos from a device on a website)

Comment: As a website, no you can't control such thing

Answer (score -1):

Look at this post
[Prevent iOS mobile safari from going idle / auto-locking / sleeping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709891/prevent-ios-mobile-safari-from-going-idle-auto-locking-sleeping)

It seems like it is currently not possible to implement. Youtube has this feature because they are using quicktime that keeps the device awake.