# Is there a way to prevent device sleeping in a iOS HTML5 web app?

Tags: html, ipad

Hi I want to know if there is a way with js or sth else that can prevent device go to sleep in a iOS web app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477424/html5-app-screen-sleep-timeout-on-ipad?rq=1

Comment: I am confused , some comments said yes and some said no :-s

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about an iOS app that uses a webview then call  the following method locally from js. This requires a native iOS app to work.

```
application.idleTimerDisabled = YES
```

Another hack from a true web app (non native) is to play an audio file constantly as some others have pointed out.

```
<audio src="loop.mp3" onended="this.play();" controls="controls" autobuffer></audio>
```